# table column as argument to a function

Tags: sql, sql-function

I have a table like

```
create table Test_Table(LoginID nvarchar(max),Team nvarchar(max))
```

It has some data like

```
insert into Test_Table values
('kbcg','Administrator,Teacher,Student'),
('kbc','Admin,Teacher,Principal')
```

Now, I want data to be displayed like

```
LoginID | Team

kbcg    | Administrator

kbcg    | Teacher

kbcg    | Student

kbc     | Admin
```

and so on...

Need a function for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        LoginID NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Team nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE values
('kbcg','Administrator,Teacher,Student'),
('kbc','Admin,Teacher,Principal')

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  LoginID,
                CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(Team, ',', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML) XMLCol
        FROM    @TABLE
)
SELECT  Vals.LoginID,
        B.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') Team
FROM    Vals CROSS APPLY
        XMLCol.nodes('/d') AS A(B)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33325)